# UITableViewDelegate heightForRowAtIndexPathUITableViewSource called for top and bottom visible cells only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin

I have a view that displays messages from conversation. It's built using `UITableView`, `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` (or `UITableViewSource` in Xamarin terms).
I have 17 cells to display, some are larger (images), some are smaller.

`estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` is called for all 17 cells, then followed by 2 calls to 
`heightForRowAtIndexPath` - for last cell #16 and for cell #8 (I believe because that is first visible cell). As a result, my conversation tableview stays blank until user scrolls it.

Questions:

1. Why `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called only for 2 cells, and not for all visible?
2. How to deal with `UITableView` being blank?

P.S. I've studied most popular answers about "`UITableView` blank until scroll" and similar questions. Reloading data in viewWillAppear, or calling it from main dispatch queue didn't help.